# Discord.py disable pinging

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
    if "USER ID" in user_message.lower(
) and username != "Ticket Tool" and "Jack PA " not in username:
    await message.delete()
    await message.channel.send(
        f'{username} Please do not ping the owners they are very busy. \nIf you need them open a ticket in ︱open-a-ticket'
    )
```

How I would I make it disable pinging for a role and for a user ID. Would I also be able to make it so my admin/ management team can ping me and it will not delete

Answer (score 0):

Since you already seem to have an object for the user that sent the message, according to the [Discord API documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord-models) you can use `ctx.guild.get_member(user_id)` to get the member object for the message sender. That object then holds a property called "roles" which lists all roles the message sender belongs to. You can then check those against your permitted role IDs and delete the message if the user is not in any of the permitted roles.

As for your second problem, your user object already holds a property called "id" that is the user ID of the sending user. Just compare that to a list of permitted users.

Comment: Ok I will try that and tell you if it works

Comment: It didnt work could you reiwrite it for me??

Comment: @Bud82jp What part exactly didn't work? I won't just write the code for you but I'll gladly give you more help here.

Comment: It didn't pick up the ID and errored and I couldn't start my bot

Comment: @RedCoca I rewrote the code and it still didnt work